# Inserting custom date and current time into Oracle database using string variables

Tags: java, database, oracle, jdbc, prepared-statement

So what I want to do is set a custom date along with the current time into the DATE type in the Oracle database.
I get the string from textField in the form of mm/dd/yyyy

```
 String tdate = textDate.getText().trim();
```

To simplify the details lets just insert the DATE into a small table.

```
 Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();                                
 int hour = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR);
 int minute = calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
 int second = calendar.get(Calendar.SECOND);
 String current_time = hour+":"+minute+":"+second;
```

now we have tdate as the string of date and current_time as the current time.

to put into a database with table defined as :

```
create table transaction(
              tranaction_num integer,
              time_of_transaction DATE);
```

now in jdbc

```
PreparedStatement pStmt = Conn.prepareStatement("insert into transaction values(?,?));
pStmt.setString(1, "1");
pStmt.setString(2, "to_date( '"+tdate+" "+current_time+"','mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi:ss')");
pStmt.executeUpdate();
```

This gives me an error as below

```
 ORA-01858: a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected
```

I know I am doing something wrong but I have tried so many things to get this working. I don't mind getting the current time some other way as long as it is working

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to pass a string, you probably want something like

```
String sqlStmt = "insert into transaction values(?,to_date(?,'mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi:ss'))"
PreparedStatement pStmt = Conn.prepareStatement(sqlStmt);
pStmt.setString(1, "1");
pStmt.setString(2, tdate+" "+current_time);
pStmt.executeUpdate();
```

From a good coding standpoint, however, you would be much better served doing a `setInt` for the first parameter and a `setDate` on the second parameter rather than passing everything as strings.

Comment: That does insert the correct value into the necessary table. Thanks a lot for that. But when I run query as SELECT * FROM transaction; in sql command line. I only get the date in the time_of_transaction column. I want it to show me the date along with the time.

Comment: @RiteshAhuja - In SQL*Plus, you would need to change your session's `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` or you'll need to use an explicit `TO_CHAR` in your query, i.e. `select to_char( time_of_transaction, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS' ) from transaction`

Comment: Thanks a lot for the prompt replies. You guys are awesome! I got my code operational.

Answer (score 4):

You should parse the date string before handing it over to the database and you should use `setInt()` for the first parameter instead of `setString()`

```
SimpleDateFormat parser = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss");

Date date = parser.parse(tdate+" "+current_time);

String sqlStmt = "INSERT INTO transaction(tranaction_num, time_of_transaction) VALUES(?,?)";
PreparedStatement pStmt = Conn.prepareStatement(sqlStmt);
pStmt.setInt(1, 1);
pStmt.setDate(2, new java.sql.Date(date.getTime()));
pStmt.executeUpdate();
```

Comment: umm... how will the database know how the fields have been arranged ? what I mean is if my date comes as mm-dd-yyyy the database cannot know that it is arranged that way. Am I correct in thinking so ?

Comment: Oh, I think I got you wrong. Yes, if `tdate` contains a date in another format than `"MM/dd/yyy"` this won't work. The `parser.parse()` would throw an exception. So the Statement `sqlStmt` wouldn't be executed.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
pStmt.setString(1, "1");
```

Use:

```
pStmt.setInt(1, 1);
```

Comment: You are right, I could have used that but it was irrelevant to my question. I just made up something for the sake of it. Nevertheless passing string works just as well.